# How to draw a customized shape using TextShape Class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

Need to draw a shape using TextShape Class. Basically wants to override drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle() method inside my TextShape class which inherits from RectangleBase.

This is the below code which I got from WPFTutorial.net. Here is the link:

> http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawRoundedRectangle.html

```
    public void DrawRoundedRectangleMine(DrawingContext dc, Brush brush, Pen pen, Rect rect, CornerRadius cornerRadius)
    {
        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();
        using (var context = geometry.Open())
        {
            bool isStroked = pen != null;
            const bool isSmoothJoin = true;

            context.BeginFigure(rect.TopLeft + new Vector(0, cornerRadius.TopLeft), brush != null, true);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopLeft.X + cornerRadius.TopLeft, rect.TopLeft.Y),
                new Size(cornerRadius.TopLeft, cornerRadius.TopLeft),
                40, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.TopRight - new Vector(cornerRadius.TopRight, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.TopRight.X, rect.TopRight.Y + cornerRadius.TopRight),
                new Size(cornerRadius.TopRight, cornerRadius.TopRight),
                40, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomRight - new Vector(0, cornerRadius.BottomRight), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomRight.X - cornerRadius.BottomRight, rect.BottomRight.Y),
                new Size(cornerRadius.BottomRight, cornerRadius.BottomRight),
                40, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.LineTo(rect.BottomLeft + new Vector(cornerRadius.BottomLeft, 0), isStroked, isSmoothJoin);
            context.ArcTo(new Point(rect.BottomLeft.X, rect.BottomLeft.Y - cornerRadius.BottomLeft),
                new Size(cornerRadius.BottomLeft, cornerRadius.BottomLeft),
                40, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, isStroked, isSmoothJoin);

            context.Close();
        }
        dc.DrawGeometry(brush, pen, geometry);
    }
```

Wants to achieve shapes like these:
1) [image: partial half capsule]
2) [image: Reverse Partial Half Capsule]

Basically I have to create two shapes  in first one, it will be a rectangle with an arc on right. And in second shape it will also be a rectangle but an arc on left.

Please help me how to create it using DrawRoundedRectangleMine() in .cs class. Not in xaml. Thanks.

Comment: What is `RectangleBase` class ?

Comment: it's a custom base class where we have kept few properties to use in child class. But that doesn't play much role in drawing the actual geometry. The main method is drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle(FillBrush, BorderPen, new Rect(this.Left, this.Top, this.Right - this.Left, this.Bottom - this.Top), CornerRadius, CornerRadius);  But we have to override this method so that we can draw the shape as we want i.e. as we have shown in above images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for:

```
    protected override void OnRender (DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        double radius = RenderSize.Height / 2;

        var sg = new StreamGeometry ();
        using (var ctx = sg.Open ())
        {
            ctx.BeginFigure (new Point(0, 0), true, true);
            ctx.LineTo (new Point(RenderSize.Width - radius, 0), true, false);
            ctx.ArcTo (new Point (RenderSize.Width - radius, RenderSize.Height), new Size (radius, radius), 0, true, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
            ctx.LineTo (new Point(0, RenderSize.Height), true, false);
        }

        var pen = new Pen (Stroke, StrokeThickness);

        drawingContext.DrawGeometry (Fill, pen, sg);
    }
```

These few lines draw exactly the first shape in an environment described here:

[How do I get my WPF Custom shape class to render in desiger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683976/how-do-i-get-my-wpf-custom-shape-class-to-render-in-desiger/39684472#39684472)

Comment: Thanks for you reply.