# How do I get my WPF Custom shape class to render in desiger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I've been stuck on this for a few days and no luck on Google or a few books.  I'm trying to create a custom shape for a UI design in WPF.  I can get the shape to render just fine in the application window when running the application, but it doesn't render in the designer.

I've stripped a test case down to the simplest I can come up with, but no luck.  The solution is a simple main window WPF application and then a C# library with the custom shape class.  Application has a project reference to the C# library and the custom shape shows up just fine in the toolbox.

The pictures below show what my shape (on the left) looks like next to a standard WPF ellipse (on the right).

Thank you for any direction you can give.

This is what it looks like when I run the application and what it should look like in designer.
[image]

However this is what I actually get (just a blue square):
[image]

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:chenmoH"
        xmlns:WpfCustomControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1" x:Class="chenmoH.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1200" FontFamily="/chenmoH;component/#Swiss911 UCm BT" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" FontSize="36" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Background="Black" Foreground="White">
    <Grid>
        <WpfCustomControlLibrary1:TestShape Fill="#FF2020DE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="319,387,0,0" Stroke="#FFDE1E1E" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Radius="50" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FF2020DE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="507,387,0,0" Stroke="#FFDE1E1E" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the TestShape.cs

```
namespace WpfCustomControlLibrary1
{
   public sealed class TestShape: Shape
   {
        public TestShape() { }
        public Double Radius
        {
            get { return (Double)this.GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Radius", typeof(Double), typeof(TestShape), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get
            {
                return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(0, 0), Radius, Radius);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks very promissing to derive from `Shape`. Unfortunately that has some ugly drawbacks: The shape does not handle resize events and you cannot tell `Shape` about a resize (that method is private) so that it asks for a new geometry. The only way I found is to ignore `Shape` and build your own control which isn't a big deal. Here it is.

```
class TestShape : FrameworkElement
{
    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue (RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue (RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Radius", typeof (double), typeof (TestShape), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Brush Fill
    {
        get
        {
            return (Brush)GetValue (FillProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue (FillProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Fill", typeof (Brush), typeof (TestShape), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (Brushes.AliceBlue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue (StrokeProperty); }
        set { SetValue (StrokeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Stroke", typeof (Brush), typeof (TestShape), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (Brushes.Beige, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue (StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue (StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("StrokeThickness", typeof (double), typeof (TestShape), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (1.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    protected override void OnRender (DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Point center = new Point (RenderSize.Width / 2, RenderSize.Height / 2);

        var pen = new Pen (Stroke, StrokeThickness);

        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Fill, pen, center, RenderSize.Width / 2 - StrokeThickness / 2, RenderSize.Height / 2 - StrokeThickness / 2);
    }
}
```

Instead of `DrawEllipse` you can use any method of the `DrawingContext` to draw you shape.

Comment: So your code behaves similar to the Shape code.  In the application it works just as expected, but in designer I just get a blank box.

Comment: Wow, that's really strange. On my systems the designer shows the shape correctly (and changes the shape when I change a property in XAML while typing).

Comment: Really.... Any chance you can zip up the solution and post it somewhere I can download?

Comment: Sorry for being late. Not sure whether your problem is solved in the meantime. You can download my test project [here](http://download.michael-goericke.de/testshape.zip)

Comment: Thanks for that.  You're project does show the shape, but for me only updates when I build the project.  i.e. if I change the radius, I don't see the change in designer until I build.  May be time to reinstall VS 2015.

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

```
return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(Radius, Radius), Radius, Radius);
```

And increase `Width` and `Height` by `5` each, in accordance with `StrokeThickness`.